# Running Total and Integer Value Allocation

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I need to be able to determine the remaining amount of point allocation for each row. Let me explain the following query:

**Variables**

- @allocated int --> already allocated points
- @to_allocate int --> the point that we need to allocate now

**View "audits"**

- ts --> date on which the points were collected
- points --> the amount of points collected

So far, I have only been able to get proper results when the data in "audits" is something like this:

**This works**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('audits') IS NOT NULL
DROP VIEW audits;

GO

CREATE VIEW audits
AS
SELECT '2000-1-1' AS ts, 10 AS points UNION ALL
SELECT '2000-1-2' AS ts, 12 AS points UNION ALL
SELECT '2000-1-3' AS ts, 123 AS points UNION ALL
SELECT '2000-1-4' AS ts, 100 AS points;

GO
```

**Does not work**

```
CREATE VIEW audits
AS
SELECT '2000-1-1' AS ts, 106 AS points UNION ALL
SELECT '2000-1-2' AS ts, 12 AS points UNION ALL
SELECT '2000-1-3' AS ts, 123 AS points UNION ALL
SELECT '2000-1-4' AS ts, 100 AS points;

GO
```

**Query**

```
DECLARE @to_allocate int = 92;
DECLARE @allocated int = 4;

WITH result
AS
(
    SELECT 
        ts,
        points,
        SUM(points) OVER(ORDER BY ts) AS total
    FROM audits
),
points
AS
(
    SELECT 
        ts,
        points,
        total,
        CASE 
            WHEN @to_allocate > total - @allocated THEN total - @allocated
            ELSE @to_allocate - SUM(total - @allocated) 
                                OVER(ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
        END as result
    FROM result
)
SELECT * FROM points
WHERE result > 0;
```

**Desired Output for "Does not work" data**

Please note that the value in result column should not be greater than point of the corresponding row. Therefore,

- when @to_allocate is 92

[image: when @to_allocate is 92]

- when @to_allocate is 200

[image: when @to_allocate is 200]

I can solve this issue by using temporary tables and loops but that's something that I don't want to do because it prevents me to use this on a function. Any help or pointing me to the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @to_allocate int = 200
DECLARE @allocated int = 4

select *,
  points - 
  case when total < @allocated then points 
       when prev < @allocated then @allocated - prev
       else 0
  end -
  case when total > @to_allocate + @allocated 
       then total - @to_allocate - @allocated 
       else 0 
  end

from
(
  select *, lag(total, 1, 0) over (order by ts asc) as prev
  from
  (
      select *, sum(points) over (order by ts asc) as total from audits
  ) X
) X
where prev < @to_allocate + @allocated
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1c77e/1)

I made the assumption that @allocated must remove values from more than just the first row, although your examples only had that.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: That sounds way too simple :P